# How to set timestamp of Apache IoTDB Version 1.1.0 to seconds to reduce the frequency of storage?

Tags: time-series, timestamp, apache-iotdb, iotdb

We are collecting time series data in seconds, but the timestamp in Apache IoTDB is a non-zero number in milliseconds. Now we want to set the timestamp stored in IoTDB directly in seconds, which remains the same with the data. I remember that Version 0.12 can achieve this configuration before, woder if the newest Version 1.1 can reduce the frequency of storage and how to do that?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please